# anchor href is misunderstood as external link with <base> tag in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm working with jquery UI tabs. (jquery 1.11.1,jQuery ui 1.11.1)

I've the following `<base>`  tag in `head>`:

```
<base href="http://mytestdomain.com/" />
```

Now when the page loads jquery UI makes two tabs out of my two `<li>`'s and then tries to load the content from base url via ajax. jQuery ui doesn't know that the `href` of anchors are not "external", but "local" hence fails to load the content.

My html:

```
<div id="container-1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1">some text1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2">some text2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1"> 
      LOREM IPSUM1
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2"> 
      LOREM IPSUM2
    </div>
 </div>
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#container-1').tabs();
    });    
</script>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/1889076/2333214 ... Suggestion: don't use `<base>` tag.

Comment: @TJ You are right. But i need the tag (i´m working with typo3 and my Project is BIIIIG.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your base tag: `<base href="http://mytestdomain.com/" />`

The links having *segments* will be interpreted like the following:

```
<a href="http://mytestdomain.com/#fragment-2">some text2</a>
```

That certainly won't work since it's pointing to a directory.

Modifying the `href` of the hyperlinks to include the remaining path till the file containing the segment will fix the issue.

For example:

```
<a href="index.html#fragment-2">some text2</a>
```

will be interpreted as

```
<a href="http://mytestdomain.com/index.html#fragment-2">some text2</a>
```

and jQuery-UI will find the element having `id` *fragment-2* from `index.html`

Comment: You are right, but look at my answer below. editing the anchot (http://mytestdomain.com/index.html#fragment2) does not work, but i do not know why....

Comment: @brandelizer don't add `mytestdomain.com/index.html#fragment2` while having a base url, either just add `index.html#fragment2` so that the base url will be prepended to it, or use `http://mytestdomain.com/index.html#fragment2` so that the base will be skipped. I tested the first method locally and it works...

Comment: OK.I had more than one tab module in the page and i have tried it only on the first. Thank you verry much for your work! I hope I can return the favor